# Can't access data from user Defaults in the lifecycle of the app

Tags: ios, userdefaults

In my app I have saved data in userDefaults and when I try to update the data with the same key it does get updated but only if I close the app and relaunch the simulator. Else if I want to access it right away(it other view Controller) it doesn't give me the the updated object but it gives me the last data that I saved with that key.
I update the data in one view controller in `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : )` and try to access it in the parent view controller.

Here is how I do that:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.isMovingFromParentViewController {
        if saveButtonPressed != true {
            // here I don't need to execute code the back button is pressed
        } else {
            if let selection = selectedMinutes {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selection, forKey: "selectedRow")
                print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "selectedRow")!) // this line prints the actual updated data but I still cannot get it in the parent view controller
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where in the parent view controller are you trying to access it?

Comment: The parent view controller is the previous controller actually and I just pop the current view controller and the app goes into parent view controller just like that.

Comment: Don't use `UserDefaults` to share data between controllers. You should have a reference to the parent view controller so you can pass the value to the parent controller directly.

Comment: I do also need this object for later when launching the app so...

Comment: Please show the code in your parent vc where you acces the value

Comment: I already managed to solve the problem by just setting the object in the parent view controller instead of in the second view controller. Can I close this answer somehow ? I'm new in here.

Comment: There should be a "delete" link at the bottom of your question (above these comments).

Answer (score -2):

You should call synchronize UserDefaults after set data

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selection, forKey: "selectedRow")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
```

Comment: Actually according to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) synchronize is unnecessary